# Azure Preview Account Approval

Tags: azure

I signed up for the preview over 24 hours ago and am still awaiting account approval.  Is this common/expected?  Or, could I have missed a step in the process?

How do I figure out which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What preview? Media Services? Virtual Machines? Web Sites? If any of these, just look at the page. It should point out that sometimes these take some time to provision, especially with the demand for these since announcing in June. You should see that your request is queued.

Having said that: This isn't a programming question.